# VSCode MSVC installation is once again giving me errors on the include path C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, codeblocks

this has been an ongoing issue with vscode where I keep getting include errors, I've finally reached my tipping point

This is the basic "Hello World" c++ program, as usual, vscode is giving me nothing

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/name/file.cpp",
    "owner": "clang-tidy",
    "code": "clang-diagnostic-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Error while processing",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 20,
            "startColumn": 10,
            "endLineNumber": 20,
            "endColumn": 11,
            "message": "'crtdbg.h' file not found",
            "resource": "/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/include/yvals.h"
        }
    ]
}]
```

This is being run on windows 10

I have tried brute forcing it through mingw installation, from mingw obtained from msys2 and these last 2-3 weeks trying to connect vscode to code::blocks just so that I can have a workspace I at least kind of understand.

This final attempt was done following the inbuild c++ tutorial where I install msvc using winget

```
winget install Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools --force --override "--wait --passive --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK"
```

I did manage to get it working with Code::Blocks, but only by the use of a tool that launches vscode at the current location, which is a little bit of progress in achieving C++ compatability, but after 4 years of trying it on and off, I doubt I can do this without external assistance.

Comment: The most likely answer is that you’ve been doing it wrong at every permutation. VS Code officially supports MinGW via MSYS2 and has official documentation on how to set it all up. You likely missed a step or two as it’s not enough to just install the compiler. I also don’t know what the heck that JSON is supposed to be.

Comment: What's your goal here? You started talking about MSVC and then you pivoted to MinGW. I've used VSCode with both MSVC and MinGW without issues, so you are doing something wrong. One issue with VScode and MSVC is that you should launch VSCode from the MSVC development environment, if you don't do that you can get into trouble.

Comment: @sweenish
I am 100% sure I am doing something wrong as I have followed the steps in the documendation exactly as seen and I'm still failing. I just want to know if someone can help me so I can finally use VSCode for c++
As for that JSON, it's the error message exactly as given by VSCode

Comment: @john 
I did check several times in I am in the correct spot, I can say that I have not failed on getting the cl command to run in VSCode. My end goal is to simply use VSCode for c++ just like I can use Code::Blocks for c++.
All of these issues are 100% from my stupidity, I am turning here because I need the help of competent human beings, under which definition I clearly do not fall under

Comment: @Codrineye I've never seen VSCode give errors as JSON. I'm not sure what you mean by 'in the correct spot' or how that relates to the points I made. You also didn't answer the question about Microsoft compiler vs MinGW. So really I'm not sure what to advise. I think it's clear however that your current VSCode installation is f**ked, so I would start again. Also don't try to force solutions, if you followed the docs and it doesn't work then don't try to fix it in some random way, that only leads to more trouble. Find out what you did wrong, and correct that.

Comment: @Codrineye 'inbuild c++ tutorial where I install msvc using winget' This is completely new to me, where did you read that? I installed MSVC by downloading it from the web site and running the installer. The official [VSCode MSVC instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) do not say anything about installing MSVC using winget.

Comment: @Codrineye I think you should also consider your current compiler installations and C++ runtimes f**ked as well. Best to start from scratch.

Comment: @john
The "inbuild c++ tutorial" I'm referring to is the one that pops up in the VSCode welcome page under "open a walkthrough" "Get started with C++ development".
The JSON file was obtained from running the code -> opening the command prompt (ctrl+`) -> checking problems and right click the error and copying it.
"I checked several times" to make sure I could actually use "cl" inside the internal command line.
I'm clueless on the difference between the compilers, I know that Code::Blocks has mingw but I don't know how to get it in VSCode, and msvc is Microsoft specific so I'll stick to it.

Comment: @john
Thank you so much for staying with me, I'm sorry for how difficult my lack of understanding things is making this
To avoid confusion, I recorded a video of everything I'm talking about and how I got everything I've provided thus far
[link](https://youtu.be/_kqA_nSfsBA) `c++`
Hope this can help you better understand what I've most deffinetely sayd poorly

Comment: @Codrineye Well that explains the JSON error message but unfortunately not much else. You should post the contents of your task.json file. You should explain how you start VSCode (I mentioned how important this is before). You should explain what you are doing to build your code, I guess you are pressing something on the keyboard, but it's not clear what from the video. There is some very strange stuff in your output window when you do the build, I have no idea what that is about.

Comment: I'm sorry fellas, as much as I'd like to accept the answer and get rid of my presents from stack overflow, I cannot until it's solved

Comment: @john
I think this shows everything that I could provide
[link](https://youtu.be/MJX9h-zokzk)
I'm sorry for the speratic movement, I had no idea what the next thing I was going to do was.
I also show what the "Answer" suggests, I very possibly could just have messed something up tho

Comment: @Codrineye Why are you trying to run code analysis? That is not the way to build a program. I'm not sure why it doesn't work (it's not something that I've ever used). Apart from that I didn't see anything obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first suggest installing with the BuildTools version of Visual Studio Installer (this takes care of installing any required workload dependencies). Here's the link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022.
Make sure to check the "Desktop Development with C++".

To be able to use any of the MSVC BuildTools from the command line (both Command Prompt and Powershell), you need to invoke one of BuildTools environment setup scripts located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\`. The script `vcvars64.bat` will supplement the command line environment with the x64 host compiler tools targeting native x64 windows. This also applies to any static analysis tools: they rely on the same environment variables as the msvc compiler tools to deduce include paths, library paths and so on.

This is all explained on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

PS: The Visual Studio installer also creates some start menu shortcuts, and new Windows Terminal profiles that does this setup automatically.